# What is the purpose of the [mistakes] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that the site has a [mistakes](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mistakes) tag.

Currently, there are 25 questions tagged such, which appear to have very little in common with each other.

The tag has no tag wiki of any kind.

**What is the intended purpose of this tag, and should it remain or could it be removed?**

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Tags are easy to create, perhaps too easy. There are now 25 pages of tags with 36 tags each. By the 16th set, usage is 7 or less.

Some of those will get used and become useful to finding similar questions. Others, such as this, not so much.

For the fact that this tag has no description, we don't know the intent of its creator. In a sense, it might answer the simple question "I wonder what mistakes people make in their finances?" But I strongly agree with you, a bad 401(k) to IRA transfer has little in common with the check that had one number written out and another number written as numerals.